# Is this a bug in gedit or a corrupted file?

Tags: gedit

I tried to open file 10.txt in http://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/tiedostot/mpera.zip by Gedit. However, there seems to be some problems. Is this a bug of a Gedit or is that file somehow corrupted? A similar file has not any problems except some slowness:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   int a=0;
   fp = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "w");
   for(a=0;a<100000;++a) {
     fprintf(fp, "fffg");
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you try it to open it with another text editor, maybe a terminal such as vim, jo or cat?

Comment: Emacs, kate and less opens the file without problems.

Comment: Is it the same length of counter a for all files?

Comment: What do you mean by "length of counter"?

Comment: I mean all files are created with a=0 to 100000 or no? because maybe the length of the line is the problem for gedit

Comment: What do you mean by "there seems to be some problems"? Is the file not loaded correctly, does gedit crash?

Comment: @HakeemWahab The files are not of fixed size.

Comment: @minerz029 It looks like letter overlaps each others and it takes long for a gedit to open the file. I tried to change the constant 100000 to 736330 in my code but I'm now unable to see the document because the opening is so slow.

Comment: yes it is a problem of displaying long content. When you try to "preview file before printing" in gedit, you'll get the correct display :) it is an editing mode issue.

Comment: @guest Yes, it does look like the letters overlap each other in gedit, but they do not overlap each other for real, they just look that way in gedit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file 10.txt opens properly in Emacs. It also can be opened in gedit, but it does not display correctly, possibly due to the fact that 10.txt is a large (736.3 kB) text file without any linefeeds. If you don't want to install anything it also can be opened in nano, but 10.txt looks more readable when it is opened using Emacs. Because 10.txt is easy to read in Emacs, it is possible to see that 10.txt does not appear to be corrupted, although the text looks like code and not like language.